# SelectedItem in ListView binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF. In my sample application I'm using a ListView to display contents of property. I don't know how to bind SelectedItem in ListView to property and then bind to TextBlock.

**Window.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Exec.App"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Main window" Height="446" Width="475" >

    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="ListViewPersonDetails" Margin="15,12,29,196" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="First name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <TextBlock Height="23" Name="textFirstNameBlock" FontSize="12" Margin="97,240,155,144">
                <Run Text="Name: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson.FirstName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Height="23" Name="textLastNameBlock" FontSize="12" Margin="97,263,155,121">
                <Run Text="Branch: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson.LastName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Height="23" Name="textAddressBlock" FontSize="12" Margin="0,281,155,103" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="138">
                <Run Text="City: " />
                <Run Text="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson.Address}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
Tman manager = new Tman();

        private List<Person> persons;
        public List<Person> Persons
        {
            get
            {
                return this.persons;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    this.persons = value;
                }

            }
        }

        private Person currentSelectedPerson;
        public Person CurrentSelectedPerson
        {
            get
            {
                return currentSelectedPerson;
            }
            set
            {
                this.currentSelectedPerson = value;
            }
        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){   
            ListViewPersonDetails.ItemsSource= manager.GetPersons();

        }
```

**Person.cs**

```
class Person
    {
        public string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged needs to send the name of the property, you are trying to send a different string for some reason?  Not sure if that's the only problem, does the list populate at all?

Comment: What behavior are you getting now?  Are you setting the DataContext of your window?  It needs to be set for those bindings to work.  Also, you are setting the ItemsSource twice, once in the XAML and once in the code.  You should only need to set it once.

Comment: @KDiTraglia Sorry, I forgot delete NotifyPropertyChanged. Know It works, but I don't know how to bind CurrentSelectedPerson property items to TextBlocks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    ListViewPersonDetails.ItemsSource= manager.GetPersons();
}
```

This is probably your problem, you shouldn't have to set the itemssource like this.  Just replace with this line...

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

This is what will bind your properties to the UI, so that all those binding statements have any meaning.

Also you need to update the binding on your textblocks to actually match the names of the properties in the Person class.

```
<TextBlock Height="23" Name="textFirstNameBlock" FontSize="12" Margin="97,240,155,144">
    <Run Text="Name: " />
    <Run Text="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson.FirstName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Height="23" Name="textLastNameBlock" FontSize="12" Margin="97,263,155,121">
    <Run Text="Branch: " />
    <Run Text="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson.LastName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Height="23" Name="textAddressBlock" FontSize="12" Margin="0,281,155,103" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="138">
    <Run Text="City: " />
    <Run Text="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson.Address}" FontWeight="Bold" />
</TextBlock>
```

EDIT:

Tested in VS, you need 1 more small thing, to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the CurrentSelectedPerson property...

```
private Person currentSelectedPerson;
public Person CurrentSelectedPerson 
{
    get { return currentSelectedPerson; }
    set 
    {
        currentSelectedPerson = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentSelectedPerson"));
    }
}
```

As an alternative this works too, a little simpler...

```
<TextBlock Height="23" Name="textFirstNameBlock" FontSize="12" Margin="97,240,155,144">
    <Run Text="Name: " />
    <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewPersonDetails, Path=SelectedItem.FirstName}" FontWeight="Bold" />
</TextBlock>
```

(repeat similar logic for other text boxes)

Comment: Thanks, that helped. In CurrentSelectedPerson property is SelectedItem. Do you know how I could bind CurrentSelectedPerson items to TextBlocks?

Comment: It should work as you listed, just correct the names to actually match the properties (currentSelectedPerson.FirstName instead of FstNamePerson).  Will edit post.

Comment: I don't know why, but it don't work. I edited my first post. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: I had to add Mode="TwoWay" to SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedPerson}" to get his to work