# getting the selected item in listview on XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I want to know the use of the property "Binding" in listview for XAML and c#
I want the get the selected item fom the list and show some of its information in a new listview 
For exemple : I have table named Registration with " username password country" as attributs so I got a listview of some people ex: OMAR OMAR USA, now I want to show the information of the selecteditem in an other textblock.

Thanks for help.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866423/selecteditem-in-listview-binding), there should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, is there a difference between WPF and windows store ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add trigger for ListViewItem that will change the value of TextBlock.Text. It would be the quickest way.

If you want to use bindings you will have to create a DataTemplate for your ListView and bind SelectedItem from there.

Comment: Yes, But I don't know how to use "Binding" neither "DataTemplate"