# How to iterate through the properties of the objects in a list?

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects and i want to iterate through the properties of the object using the 'previous' and 'next' buttons in WPF.
For example if i'm iterating through the properties of an object then by clicking the 'previous' button i encounter the properties of the object located before the object i was currently iterating through and same case for the 'next' button ...

if i have a Student class containing properties first and last name and number of student objects stored in studentList then how would i do that?
I am only concerned about the implementation of the eventHandler method for 'next' and 'previous' buttons

```
class Student
{
    private string firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
    private string lastName;

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
    private string city;

    public string City
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { city = value; }
    }

}

private void btnCreateStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        student1.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
        student1.City = txtCity.Text;

        studentList.Add(student1);

        MessageBox.Show("Student Created");

        txtFirstName.Clear();
        txtLastName.Clear();
        txtCity.Clear();
    }

private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // need implementation code
    }
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // need implementation code
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: These types of questions work better with more code, less abstract description.

Comment: the question contains basic coding which you can assume by reading the question ... i just need the eventHandler methods for the click event of 'next' and 'previous' buttons

Comment: The event handler methods for the Click event of these two buttons contain basic coding which you can assume by imagining the problem to be solved.

Comment: You aproach is wrong. You have a wpf application, so you have to bind your controls to viewmodel. See sample for doingit with listrview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866423/selecteditem-in-listview-binding

Comment: i am not concerned with the binding or something else. I am just concerned with the implementation of the two event handler methods @MaksimSimkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not using any binding stuff, you should write a helper method that populates your UI with the values from your currently selected `Student` object:

```
private void bindStudent(Student student) {
    if (student != null) {
        txtFirstName.Text = student.FirstName;
        txtLastName.Text = student.LastName;
        txtCity.Text = student.City;
    }
    else { // Just a fail-safe.
        txtFirstName.Clear();
        txtLastName.Clear();
        txtCity.Clear();
    }
}
```

Then your Next and Previous buttons only need to fetch the respective object from your `studentList` and call the method with it. One thing you need to do is to remember which object in your list is currently selected in order to get the "next" and "previous" objects.

```
private int curSelectionIndex = -1;

private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (curSelectionIndex - 1 >= 0)
  {
      curSelectionIndex--;
      bindStudent(studentList[curSelectionIndex]);
  }
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (curSelectionIndex + 1 < studentList.Count)
  {
      curSelectionIndex++;
      bindStudent(studentList[curSelectionIndex]);
  }
}
```

Your question didn't specify what you want to do with the UI after creating a fresh student, so I didn't do anything in regards to updating that selection.

Comment: thank you it worked actually i could not figure out how to keep track which object is currently showing